# Icon of warning is shown while there are no output of a warning(Qt Creator IDE)

Tags: c++, qt, ide, qt-creator

My problem is that I get **fake** warning icons but there is no message of a warning.Why fake? Because when I did an obvious mistake which should show warning, I could find the message in the issues.

*These fakes warnings do not show any messages they are just standing there.*

When I compiled my code on various IDE s no message was shown that why I am completely sure that is not a fault of code.

[image: Look at Image]
IDE:
Qt Creator 3.6.1
OS :
Arch Linux..

Edit: They show messages but only when I move my cursor to a particular one. The question is how can I move them to be shown in issues?

Comment: Charlie, they may not be fake. Go to Compile Output (Alt + 4) and see if there are compiler warnings. There seems to be a bug in the Qt Creator, where they don't show up in the Issues window.

Comment: I do not see any of warnings in output.

Comment: And what's the message when you move the cursor over a particular one?

Comment: For example that there is conversion between types.

Comment: Well not by chance it was built in Qt Creator and it is said that it is necessary to work with openframeworks.

Comment: @Charllie - who said that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have the clang code model enabled - it is a huge nag, complains just about anything.

In Creator go to Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Model, then uncheck `Use Clang Code Model`.

Disabling it will also improve the performance of Creator, but in case you chose to keep it enabled and still want all those warnings to go away, you have no other choice but to fix your code so it is up to the clang code model.

The warnings aren't fake, it is just the the clang code model, as current configured in your IDE is at maximum strictness, it will complain about a lot of things which are practically harmless, just because theoretically they are not considered "best/proper practice".

Note that you can also configure the code model by adding or removing individual flags, in Creator 4 there will also be different presets for it.